# I am Round and I am Flat - Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I am round and I am flat
>
> I can be shiny or I can be matte.
>
> I can be solid or I can be clear
>
> Know the answer yet, my dear?
>
> No? Okay, well here's a hint:
>
> I'm not bourbon, a toad, or a goose or a vent
>
> I don't do well in all kinds of weather
>
> But mostly I manage to keep it together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be

> Adhesive tape!

```
I am round and I am flat
```

> Tape is typically sold in a roll, which is round. When unrolled, the tape itself is flat.

```
I can be shiny or I can be matte.
```

> It is sold in a variety of colors. For example, duct tape is often silver (shiny), and painter's tape is a solid color (matte).

```
I can be solid or I can be clear
```

> In addition to the opaque matte colors, you can have transparent tapes like Scotch tape.

```
I'm not bourbon, a toad, or a goose or a vent
```

> Scotch tape is not scotch the alcohol, or any drink, such as bourbon.
>  Adhesive tape is unrolled and extended before sticking to things. A toad's tongue works in a similar way, but a tape roll is not a toad.
>  Duct tape is sometimes called "duck tape", but it's not a duck (or goose).
>  The "duct" in duct tape does not actually refer to an air duct (or vent).

```
I don't do well in all kinds of weather
```

> When wet (and/or exposed to heavy winds), tape can lose its adhesiveness.

```
But mostly I manage to keep it together.
```

> The purpose of adhesive tape is to keep things held together.

Comment: Yes! Perfect! And the toad part was for "Frog Tape" which is another name for Painter's Tape but it's a little less well known than the others.